# How to convert var into date time using c#?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I wan to convert a var into data and time how to do that

```
var t = (from li in list2 select li).Max();
```

the above code give me a output `2014-06-03 10:07:31 AM` now I want to convert this into '03_06_2014_10_07_31'

so first I tried to change the format to `'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'` by using the below so that I can use some split and so on and make it `'03_06_2014_10_07_31'`

```
DateTime dfg = DateTime.ParseExact(t, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it showing

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I want to change `2014-06-03 10:07:31 AM` into `03_06_2014_10_07_31`

Comment: When it's in a `DateTime` variable, it doesn't **have** a format. So if you want to take something and produce something that has the format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, the result type had better be a `string`.

Comment: Why do you want to perform a split on the resulting string?

Comment: my output from linq is 2014-06-03 10:07:31 AM and i want to change into 03_06_2014_10_07_31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DateTime` has no implicit format, it is just a `DateTime` value. You can format it as a `string` value.

From [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

In your case, they are not.

Use `yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss tt` format instead.

Here an example in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string s = "2014-06-03 10:07:31 AM";
DateTime dfg = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss tt",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dfg.Dump();
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/pwwoWG)</kbd>.

After that, you can format your `DateTime` with [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
dfg.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

prints `03/06/2014 10:07:31`

or

```
dfg.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

prints `03_06_2014_10_07_31`

Comment: DateTime dfg = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt",    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  i used this but it still showing me 2014-06-03 10:07:31 AM only i want to convert to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @user2380844 A `DateTime` doesn't have any format. You can format it as a `string`. That's why you need to use `DateTime.ToString()` method for formatting.

Comment: hey this is not working when the date is 26/5/2014 15:38:50 pls gelp

Comment: @user2380844 Don't you have a standard pattern for your datetime values? You need to use `dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format for `26/5/2014 15:38:50` value.