# Milliseconds missing when insert date time to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I m using user define table parameter for bulk insert, i create the user define table and column name is ModifiedDate in datatype for datetime

when i pass the value into sql it will insert fine but it missed milliseconds value then how can i install this

My user define table

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Test] AS TABLE(
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

My Sp

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CP_UpdateData]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @Test Test Readonly,

  INSERT into Test(ModifiedDate)
       Values(ModifiedDate);
```

but here my datetime value is missing millisecond, could you please help any suggestion for resolve this issues

in by c# code

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "CP_UpdateData";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Test", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = ConvertToDataTable(list);                       
    con.Open();
    var dataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
}

public DataTable ConvertToDataTableCampaingList(List<Test> list)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
    {
     dataTable.Columns.Add("ModifiedDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
     foreach (var data in list)
        {
        var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow["ModifiedDate"] = data.ModifiedDate;
         dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: I hope this will not be your first post, Please care to keep proper formatting while posting

Comment: sidenote: sql server's `datetime` data type best accuracy is 3 milliseconds. If you need milliseconds accuracy you should either use `Time` datatype or `DateTime2`.

Comment: @Zohar, DATETIME still returns milliseconds, so DATETIME2 would not solve the problem since it is his compiler (C#) that is causing the errors.
By definition, VAR in C# is an implicitly typed local variable. [var (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: 3 milliseconds enough for me but it always 000 in my case that's my problem

Comment: Oh, really? From a simple google search, `DATETIME` has no implicit format, so that may be the culprit here.combined with your compiler's default rendering of `DATETIME`. *user2380844* [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927093/how-to-convert-var-into-date-time-using-c) has a similar question where the answer was to explicitly translate `DATETIME` into `string` (Which, incidentally, you do in `SQL` too).

Comment: @clifton_h there is no problem while it convert to var but in my db it have the date time datatype so i need to send this into datetime in user define table but it miss the milliseconds :(

Comment: Ok, cart before the horse. Where does the `DATETIME` values come from? Your DB or the C# program? What happens when you translate it into string directly first, as the link describes? If your still getting a TRUNCATION of values, then check upstring in your code.

Comment: When i convert the
var date = (DateTime.Parse(datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")));
it return correct  milliseconds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115921/discussion-between-clifton-h-and-manikandan).

Comment: @clifton_h: I know, I was only pointing out that it's accuracy is limited to 3 milliseconds. that's why it was a side note. I didn't even try to to answer the question.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem but couldn't. I did get milliseconds every time. My c# code was exactly like yours except I've used `DateTime.Now` as the value to insert into the dataRow. Perhaps the `data.ModifiedDate` is already with milliseconds set to 0?

Comment: @Manikandan please *simplify* the code and include the code that actually generates the date. This code already does some really weird things, like using `Type.GetType` instead of just `typeof(DateTime)`. It also uses `ConvertToDataTable` but you post a different method. The stored procedure code doesn't compile either - you can't write `VALUES(@Test ModifiedDate)`. Perhaps you have yet-another-typo that removes milliseconds

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos VALUES( ModifiedDate) only  i used mistakenly i posted  VALUES(@Test ModifiedDate), typeof(Datetime) also wont work

Comment: @ZoharPeled i get millisecond always 000 that the my problem, in by table the entry look like 2016-06-28 12:53:20.000

Comment: I understand the problem, but can't reproduce it. BTW, your insert statement should look like this: `INSERT INTO ZZZ_TEMP_TABLE (ModifiedDate) SELECT ModifiedDate FROM @Test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer being in the `CHAT ROOM` discussion, I will post it here:
The problem is implicit conversions and how each compiler treats the data. `DATETIME` by default has no defined `FORMAT`, so `SQL` implicitly converts the data.

> So the issue is when your storing it into the table as the Default
>   formatting is the problem CREATE TABLE #Example2 (TIMES DATETIME NOT
>   NULL)  INSERT INTO #Example2 (TIMES)  VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME,
>   GETDATE(), 9))  , (CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(20) ) ) Notice how the
>   default in a simple string actually drops milliseconds since its
>   format is wrong

Notice the solution was `explicitly` defining the format:

- Manikandan wrote:

  > When i convert the var date =
  >   (DateTime.Parse(datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))); it
  >   return correct milliseconds

Converting the DATETIME to string makes it portable and in a data type that will not TRUNCATE the data. However, use a proper CONVERT(data type, expression, style) if you ensure accuracy.

- Manikandan wrote:

  > DECLARE @TEMP_Result TABLE 
  >       ( 
  >       ModifiedDate  DATETIME 
  >       )
  >
  > ```
  > DECLARE @TEMp TABLE 
  > ( 
  > ModifiedDate  varchar(50) 
  > ) 
  >
  > declare @timestring varchar(50) 
  >
  > set @timestring = '2016-06-28 12:53:20.850' 
  >
  > Insert into @TEMp(ModifiedDate) 
  > values(@timestring) 
  >
  > Insert into @TEMP_Result(ModifiedDate) 
  > select Convert(datetime, ModifiedDate) from @TEMp 
  >
  >
  > select * from @TEMP_Result
  > ```

**MORAL**: BEWARE OF IMPLICIT CONVERSIONS

- `Implicit` conversion are guesses and determined by the compiler. They are not dependable *as this case shows*.
- `CAST` is not an explicit conversion, and may return the wrong format. Use `CONVERT` in `SQL` to avoid implicit conversions.
- Storing `DATETIME` in a string makes it portable, avoids `TRUNCATION` of data, and is easily converted to the correct format in `SQL`.